# How to Set Stored Procedure Output To Variables Directly

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Is there a way to set the output of a stored procedure to variables in SQL without creating a temp table?

I was thinking something like

`set (var1, var2, etc) = exec name_of_stored_procedure(arg1, arg2, etc)`

Comment: What does the procedure return?

Comment: I think there is more to this question though... what would you do with the variables after you have them?

Comment: Pass them into other procedures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.  If the stored procedure is returning scalar values, then you should pass them in as output parameters.  That is the best method.  Consider modifying the procedure.

If the stored procedure has a `SELECT` statement that returns the values, well, consider switching to input parameters.  I'm not a fan of using stored procedures this way.  But SQL Server let's you put the results of the last `SELECT` into a table:

```
create table t (
    var1 . . . ,
    var2 . . . ,
    . . .
);

insert into t
    exec(name_of_stored_procedure(arg1, arg2, . . .));
```

This is described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Oh, did I mention using OUTPUT parameters to return scalar values?  ;)

Comment: Agreed with the OUTPUT parameters part, but I'm betting "how" will be their next question :)